# Tracking Build Status in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

We are in the progress of setting up Jenkins to manage our build system.  I would like to use Jenkins to track the full lifecycle of the build.  We have very few automated tests that are run (I know, I know, we are working on that), so I would like a way to update the status of the build from build completion to QA completion with different status like Alpha Ready, Beta Ready, RC and Release.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only looking for a way to 'flag' your builds you could use a [promotion](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) for that. The promoted builds plugin is meant to perform a actual action, so I would suggest making the action a publish/copy one that uploads your artifacts to a directory that would also convey the status e.g. /alpha, /beta, /rc, etc. You can restrict who is allowed to perform a promotion if you want.

Personally I'd track the status of the build in a separate bugtracker using milestones and only check the 'keep this build forever' and add a comment on the builds on jenkins that are important for this. (of course you'd need your backups set up correctly for this, otherwise you should copy your build artifacts and the steps to reproduce them to another safe location)

Comment: Are you saying that you would create a bug for each build or just the ones that were being tested?

Comment: I would create a milestone/release/version/tag (depending on availablilty and naming in bugtracker) for every build that is being tested.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make each step in your build lifecycle a different Jenkins job and then have the preceeding job trigger the next job? Then you could name each job with the stage in the lifecycle.

Splitting it out into jobs can make it clear at which step your build failed and can make it easier to start the build process from where it failed if it fails.